# R- Every Other Number of a Sequence Negative

Tags: r, vector, pi

I'm trying to generate a series of vectors to calculate the approx. value of Pi using this formula given:
Pi = 4 (1- (1/3) + (1/5) -(1/7)...
for 7 terms.
I made a sequence for the denominator values as such

```
number.terms3c <-7
seq.vec3c <- seq(from = 1, by = 2 , length.out = number.terms3c)
```

and would then use that vector to get the reciprocals with

```
recip.vec3c <- (1/ seq.vec3c)
```

But in order to sum them, I was thinking I needed to get every other value to be negative (hence the alternating + and - values.

Is there a simple code I can learn to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rep` to create what you want to multiply by.

```
> recip.vec3c * rep(c(1,-1), length.out = number.terms3c)
[1]  1.00000000 -0.33333333  0.20000000 -0.14285714  0.11111111 -0.09090909
[7]  0.07692308
```

with that said... I only used that to avoid the warning.  If you don't particularly care about that you can be fast and loose with the vector recycling that R does and just multiply by c(1, -1).

```
> recip.vec3c * c(1, -1)
[1]  1.00000000 -0.33333333  0.20000000 -0.14285714  0.11111111 -0.09090909
[7]  0.07692308
Warning message:
In recip.vec3c * c(1, -1) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember you can generate a sequence of `n` numbers in R with `1:n`, and you can get any number modulo 2 by doing `x %% 2`. So `1:n %% 2` gives a repeating sequence of `1 0 1 0 1 0`. Therefore multiplying this by 2 and subtracting 1 gives the repeating sequence `1 -1 1 -1 1 -1...`. You can therefore use `(2*(1:n %% 2) - 1)` as your numerators.

Similarly, your denominators are just a sequence of odd numbers, given by `1:n * 2 - 1`

This means you can write a simple arithmetic function to sum the first n terms of this expansion like this:

```
pi_fracts <- function(n) sum(4*(2*(1:n %% 2) - 1)/(1:n * 2 - 1))
```

So you can do

```
pi_fracts(7)
#> [1] 3.283738
```

or even

```
pi_fracts(1000000)
#> [1] 3.141592
```